# Parsing error after copying new policy files to central store

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

A few months ago we upgrade our DCs from 2008 to 2008 R2.

Two weeks ago I saw that I didn't copy the new admx/adml files to the central store.

Because I want to use the new policies, I copied all local files from one of the DC's `%windir%\PolicyDefinitions` to the central store.

Today I opened `rsop.msc` on one of the member servers and got a "parsing error":

```
**ADML**
Administrative Templates
Encountered an error while parsing.
Expected one of the Following possible element(s), < text >,
< decimalTextBox >, < textBox >, < checkBox >, < comboBox >,
< dropdownList >, < listBox >, but Found < multiTextBox > instead.
File
\\contoso.com\sysvol\contoso. . . TerminalServer-Server.adml, line 198, column 60

**ADMX**
Administrative Templates
Encountered an error while parsing.
Encountered an unknown error while parsing (error = 0x87400001): -2025848831 (0x87400001)
File
\\contoso.com\sysvol\conto. . . \Terminalserver-Server.admx, line 9, column 41
```

After restore of the old admx/adml it worked without problems.
Any ideas, whats wrong with the new admx/adml Templates?

**Update 16.01.2012**
Could it be possible that the old "2008 SP2" Terminal Servers cannot work with the new (Remote Desktop Services) policies implemented with "2008 R2"?

Answer (score 3):

See http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/12/09/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-and-the-group-policy-central-store.aspx as it explains the reason. Was the member server Windows Server 2008?

Comment: thanks for the down vote. can I suggest a comment to go with it the next time explaining why? The link explains the cause is compatibility issues in the templates with Vista/2008.

Comment: No, our DCs was running on 2008 R2 before we copied the new policy files to the central store.
The Windows 7 SP1 Management Workstation has the new RSAT installed.

Comment: I won't DV the answer, because helped me for find a solution to my problem. But maybe the DV came because there is only a link and not the answer: "... Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."
And there is my Up Vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but it helped me get to the correct solution. I solved this problem by ensuring i had the corresponding adml language file in the en-us folder. I would make sure you have the terminalserver.admx in your policydefinitions folder.